# C# with SQL Server - Time portion of Datetime2(3) field is always being set to 00:00:00:000

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to save a datetime in sql server with a time value.
There are 2 columns of interest in the table:

```
startDate datetime2(3) null
startTime time(0) null
```

Here's the processing of records before insert. The data variable is a list of values imported from a spreadsheet:

```
DateTime dtest;
DateTime dtimetest;
if (DateTime.TryParse(data.startDate, out dtest))
{
  entity.startDate = dtest;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(data.startTime, out dtimetest))
  {
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(dtimetest.Hour, dtimetest.Minute, dtimetest.Second);
    entity.startDate = dtest.Date + ts;
    entity.startTime = ts;
  }   
}
```

My goal is to store the correct time in the startDate column so i can get rid of the startTime column.
The above approach is not working.  Here are the results:

```
startDate                 startTime
2021-04-17 00:00:00.000   18:09:00
2024-10-01 00:00:00.000   09:09:00
2021-04-03 00:00:00.000   04:09:00
2023-09-01 00:00:00.000   21:09:00
2022-12-30 00:00:00.000   16:09:00
2023-12-30 00:00:00.000   21:09:00
2022-06-03 00:00:00.000   22:09:00
2023-04-21 00:00:00.000   08:09:00
2021-01-19 00:00:00.000   02:09:00
2024-10-13 00:00:00.000   21:09:00
```

Why is the time not getting set in the startDate column?  Could it be a database setting?
It's also worth mentioning that the time does get set correctly when run in the development environment.  Once a release was created and installed on a server, i noticed the time not being set.

Comment: What is `entity`? How is the property configured? If you used `date` as the type in the DbContext configuration, or if the property's access methods trim the time part, you'll only get the date. Or you may not be storing the correct object. Whatever it is, the problem is in the code

Comment: you're right, the type in dbcontext is date.  After i posted this i used profiler to see the values coming in and there is no time with the date.